# load html in flex 3.5 and more

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I want to load some html page [see this](http://www.deitte.com/IFrameDemo3/IFrameDemo.html) in Flex 3.5 or more I followed [this](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm) tutorial but somehow i think it only works in Flex 2, I even tried by unchecking `Generate HTML wrapper file` but no luck. Can somebody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to dissapoint you, but HTML with Inner Frame and Flex is not a good option.

If you want a wysiwyg html editor, I suggest you to create your own editor, or you can buy one.
And if you need to open a new window of contents, you should open a new window in the HTML way, outside the Flex App.

My experience in IFrames with Flex was with this [google code](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/). Some people have modified it and posted it, and you should find in other sites, doing the same thing: It works in some cases, but, for example, will not work if you need to put more complex needs in your App along with IE compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, even I am looking into the same link.. hopefully it works.. so do you mean it has compatibility issues with IE? Also I am loading a very simple html page, hosted in one of my servers

Comment: That's right, compatibility with IE. Maybe you can encounter domain issues also, by transfering data between them. This concerns all browsers, for security reasons.

Comment: I have it working now, anyways I am also putting my answer as reference. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

search about iFrame in FLEX application will give you the best result. I have used iFrame but still not get the expected result so i have ignored that thing to implement in my project but might be you can get better result. Best Luck. Have a nice day.

one of the advice from my senior i get is "when you are passing from the firewall you can't get the result in iFrame." so this sentence might be useful to you.

Comment: great stuff guys!! i checked what Abishek has mentioned, it's working for me, i do have firewall, but working fine

Answer (score 1):

I used this [Guide](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide) to make it work. (mostly about adding `wmode="opaque"` to the html)

Download the `flexiframe` from this [location](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/)

Use `xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/"` in your component

and `<flexiframe:IFrame id="iFrame"  label="Google"  source="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"  />`

That's it.. this worked for me and surprisingly it works on IE, Firefox  and chrome

**Note**: You can also use pdf